# C++ std::string is empty but full of '\0'

Tags: c++, string, crash

I have a file which contain some numbers, all in one line . I would like to read this file and put this line to a string variable.
So as it contains only one line, the `getline()` method should works only once

But It's not the case. It works twice. I notice that first my string_descriptor contains the number (so it's okey) but after getline take another line and this time it's empty but by looking at the debugger the string contains a lot of \O\ like 10 times.

```
\O\O\O\O\O\O\O\O\O\O\O\O\O\O\O\
```

[image]

And it bothers me because after I'm doing some processing and because of that my app crashs.

So what I'm doing is the following :

```
 fs.open (desc.c_str (), std::ios::in);
 string line;
 if(!fs.is_open())
 {
      cout<<"\n Cannot open the text.txt file";
 }
 else
 {
   std::string string_descriptor;
   while (!fs.eof ())
   {

     getline( fs , line);
     if (line != "" && line.find_first_not_of(' ') != std::string::npos && !line.empty())
     {

      string_descriptor = line;
      std::cout << "String descriptor : " << string_descriptor << std::endl;

     }
  }
}
```

So why it happened ? And especially how can I handle that ? I tried to handle that by doing the following but It's still the same :

```
if (line != "" && line.find_first_not_of(' ') != std::string::npos && !line.empty())
```

I checked my file and there is no space at the end of the file, so far I know.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should not loop using `eof()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Does your file contain the nul chars?

Comment: No only numbers so far I know

Comment: @stark there were an invisible space at the end of the line...Do you know how can i check that for my future processing ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the second iteration of the loop change the loop

```
   while (!fs.eof ())
   {

     getline( fs , line);
     //...
```

the following way

```
   while ( getline( fs , line) )
   {
     //...
```

Also this condition

```
if (line != "" && line.find_first_not_of(' ') != std::string::npos && !line.empty())
```

can look more simpler

```
if ( line.find_first_not_of(' ') != std::string::npos )
```

Comment: Thank for the modification but even by changing in this way but still got the same issue...

Comment: @lilouch Maybe the file contains two records and the last one is empty. What is the problem?

Comment: Actually, my file contains only one line with number and my line variable should contains only the numbers but it seems that it loops again and I got an empty string from line. I don't want that and that's why I used the IF condition...But I still get an empty string with full of \0\

Comment: @lilouch It means that the file contains more than one record and nothing more.

Comment: Thank for your answer but on my file, I have just one line and not two...that's the thing

Comment: @lilouch You should check the file in binary representation. It can contain for example last symbol 1Ah.

Comment: Indeed there were an invisible space in the file :/. But do you have an idea how can i check that for my future processing ?

Comment: @lilouch This does not create a problem for the file processing.

Comment: Actually yes because after my split my string by using the ' ' delim to put every number to a vector of string and then I convert each number from string to float. But as the end of my line contain a big nul string, it cannot convert the string and crashed...

Comment: @lilouch The problem is not related with the file. The problem is in your code where you evidently incorrectly process lines.